# useless implicit keyword assigned to method ? / Play framework 2

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

As the [official documentation of Play framework](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaSessionFlash) recommends, we can use an implicit `request` in order to improve access to some objects associated to the request.

Sample:

```
def index = Action { implicit request =>
  session.get("connected").map { user =>
    Ok("Hello " + user)
  }.getOrElse {
    Unauthorized("Oops, you are not connected")
  }
}
```

This is due to the addition of the following `implicit` method belonged to the `Controller` trait:

```
/**
   * Retrieves the session implicitly from the request.
   *
   * For example:
   * {{{
   * def index(name:String) = Action { implicit request =>
   *   val username = session("username")
   *   Ok("Hello " + username)
   * }
   * }}}
   */
  implicit def session(implicit request: RequestHeader) = request.session
```

Question: Why does this method is declared itself as `implicit`? Isn't it enough to only declare `request` parameter as `implicit`?

I expected to see that instead:

`def session(implicit request: RequestHeader) = request.session`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `implicit` keyword is indeed not necessary at all to allow your sample to compile. So either it is an error in Play!, or the additional `implicit` keyword was intended to play another role.

In particular with this additional `implicit` keyword, you can call a method that expects an implicit value of type `Session` even if you only have an implicit value of type `RequestHeader` in scope (`session` also defines an implicit value of type `RequestHeader` , provided that you have an implicit value of type `RequestHeader` in scope).